# How to Install scipy in Windows 7 with Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I'm having trouble installing `scipy`. When I run

`python -m pip install scipy`

I get the following messages:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py run on 01/14/15 15:56:16
Downloading/unpacking scipy
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
  URLs to search for versions for scipy:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.3-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.whl#md5=4bc791c9f37645380cab2843e63d18db (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.3-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl#md5=ca634955b1757fe5e22c6a8a035bb328 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.3-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl#md5=0042a2e09d1632b47ed4fdb411cf9821 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.10.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=310a518b189f32116da85e1762126b1a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.11.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=b385333496b8b25a5782c2a7a35413d3 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.12.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=8230187d0f2580bbdf78fa1b56b01087 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=0b3c405ba421f43cf97837c5aa172515 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=f56df58dd416119a23d1c58316da5c26 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=d3728a6d43c3265003db3781cbd4660f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=6bdf3109da07d8d6caeb438777d312dc (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1rc1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=1e6c155aa0bf5a248d3e46cf1d0ff44a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1rc1.dev_205726a-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=25c79e26aef2696a651c611b113c4965 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1rc1.dev_52fb336-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=77ed947568d9d7b42f71ca84dce6b590 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.15.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=7c431a473ac65fd7cab4859c3743088b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.0-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=d451fff29fd3d7aa501d6206bfed15f2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.0-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=f2b504a8e3d5ee0ae33d7052a994a029 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.0-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=0ff3c20cb8e9c5c38e5a18cda3178ca7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=423c77aa343f76c30788166400696f68 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1rc1-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=bbe1317ca465c1246a71a86a5c380f0f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1rc1.dev_205726a-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=27038263a15a4c125ded37f7f1dff9d3 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1rc1.dev_52fb336-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=b7514dd98239f5ec98fe290947a62906 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/s/scipy/scipy-0.15.0-cp33-cp33m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=f6c96a2cb737ad9f3f47db5089f8eba4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.0-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=dcd20dad203d301f0b5ec7aa0bb49aa3 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.0-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=f5cf7e6eec6f7d41c6e46f32834d675d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.0-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#md5=de679794f46812c784845835371539f4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=1c9eca63055d0e64b9b9d241ec5f9c0f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1rc1-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=ebdd363cfce65ceb62c456a8e6047ef7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1rc1.dev_205726a-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=755003a1d318c5b7e47c3e3b930f955d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1rc1.dev_52fb336-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=45c8e4c39aff1eb30b870796e039adce (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/s/scipy/scipy-0.15.0-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=4b7fc70b09576ef91e3ff4b005816379 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.10.0.tar.gz#md5=e357c08425fd031dce63bc4905789088 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.10.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.10.0.zip#md5=d1a4242266739433dcfe2096b0ab4007 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.10.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.10.1.tar.gz#md5=6ad976549e22e04ca93e70cf55b70a22 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.10.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.10.1.zip#md5=4156cc1b765eb186de9518a94b6c3518 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.10.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.11.0.tar.gz#md5=842c81d35fd63579c41a8ca21a2419b9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.11.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.11.0.zip#md5=40b700ddde9ddab643b640fff7a9d753 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.11.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.12.0.tar.gz#md5=8fb4da324649f655e8557ea92b998786 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.12.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.12.0.zip#md5=e4b9f3cb2e965fc8751faedfb9164d08 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.12.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.12.1.tar.gz#md5=906278290152fedfe79029371ca584a5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.12.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.12.1.zip#md5=3f23065fc45152c92c3588dad2f20c62 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.12.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.0.tar.gz#md5=ffa1e9bfd2bbdf3f17f4cf8139084098 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.13.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.0.zip#md5=bd588ce8255e4d5427b5b19e9da2d4c7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.13.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.1.tar.gz#md5=e082fe358a2b39cff235e5af4240f5a5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.13.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.1.zip#md5=485411032b02583b4eb63caec6f2a916 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.13.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.2.tar.gz#md5=fcd110802b0bf3505ba567cf831566e1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.13.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.2.zip#md5=9befa30e546fba762a0c1695a509f731 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.13.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.3.tar.gz#md5=0547c1f8e8afad4009cc9b5ef17a2d4d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.13.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.13.3.zip#md5=20ff3a867cc5925ef1d654aed2ff7e88 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.13.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.0.tar.gz#md5=d7c7f4ccf8b07b08d6fe49d5cd51f85d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.14.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.0.zip#md5=7ee4fa9e756bab6b46b79f77c821cb68 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.14.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1.tar.gz#md5=1bfedd3197b3e3f8cd131ae2c06a1bf5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.14.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.1.zip#md5=4bfc35d3683e0ef397157f84040df5b0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.14.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.15.0.tar.gz#md5=639112f077f0aeb6d80718dc5019dc7a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.15.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.15.0.zip#md5=09641b11ac17f1c141979c60a3f60895 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.15.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.8.0.tar.gz#md5=f0bfc6141b90e6a31555b31486602251 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.8.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.9.0.tar.gz#md5=ebfef6e8e82d15c875a4ee6a46d4e1cd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.9.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.9.0.zip#md5=a37933c9e3c4fdf8d087624cd7dcb47d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/), version: 0.9.0
  Using version 0.15.0 (newest of versions: 0.15.0, 0.15.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.0, 0.13.3, 0.13.3, 0.13.2, 0.13.2, 0.13.1, 0.13.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.0, 0.12.1, 0.12.1, 0.12.0, 0.12.0, 0.11.0, 0.11.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.0, 0.8.0)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.15.0.tar.gz#md5=639112f077f0aeb6d80718dc5019dc7a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/)
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_cooluser\scipy\setup.py) egg_info for package scipy
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'docs'
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'f2py.1'
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1526: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1535: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

I HAD TO CUT SOME STUFF OUT HERE TO MAKE IT FIT IN THE CHARACTER LIMIT

        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 593, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 623, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 809, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1015, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1003, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'

non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'docs'

non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'f2py.1'

non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'

Running from numpy source directory.

C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1526: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1535: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1538: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1432: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1443: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

    the LAPACK environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1446: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 177, in run

    self.run_command("egg_info")

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 10, in run

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 153, in run

  File "C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 164, in build_sources

  File "C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 299, in build_library_sources

  File "C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources

  File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 684, in get_mathlib_info

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 243, in try_link

    self._check_compiler()

  File "C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 57, in _check_compiler

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 259, in query_vcvarsall

    raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")

distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1000, in run_setup

    run_setup(setup_script, args)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 50, in run_setup

    lambda: execfile(

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 100, in run

    return func()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 52, in <lambda>

    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\compat.py", line 78, in execfile

    exec(compile(source, fn, 'exec'), globs, locs)

  File "setup.py", line 251, in <module>

  File "setup.py", line 243, in setup_package



  File "C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-pccllqug\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup

    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))

SystemExit: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_cooluser\scipy\setup.py", line 249, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_cooluser\scipy\setup.py", line 246, in setup_package

    setup(**metadata)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 239, in __init__

    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_eggs

    parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 564, in resolve

    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 802, in best_match

    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 814, in obtain

    return installer(requirement)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_egg

    return cmd.easy_install(req)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 593, in easy_install

    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 623, in install_item

    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 809, in install_eggs

    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1015, in build_and_install

    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1003, in run_setup

    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_cooluser...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_cooluser\scipy
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 325, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\cooluser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_cooluser\scipy
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing [`numpy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and [`scipy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) from Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows repository. These are already compiled and statically linked to Intel's MKL library for increased performance, so all you need to do is download the appropriate `.exe` file for your version and "bit-ness" of Python, then run the downloaded file and it'll install.

Comment: This worked fine for me some months ago.  Make sure to install numpy first.

Comment: I don't see a version for Python 3.4 there.

Answer (score 1):

This is related.

I am having problems installing Scipy wheel file (no exe available) for Python 2.7.9, 64 bit on Window 7.

I have downloaded the whl file: scipy-0.15.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl from Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows repository, into my Downloads folder.

I have then tried the following at cmd prompt:

pip2 install c:\users\ name \Downloads\scipy-0.15.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

And I get weird error
Exception Traceback etc etc.

If I use just pip, I get unknown or unsupported command 'install'. And yes, I have set my environment variable PATH to include both

C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts

And numpy MKL 1.9.1. 64 bit is already installed.

And I have downloaded and successfully installed wheel package.

Answer (score 1):

With advice, the answer to my problem is:

At the CMD prompt, specify the path to pip.exe and include double quotes for the path to where the whl file is downloaded.

For example,

> C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install "C:\Users\ name \Downloads\scipy-0.15.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl"