# "failed with error code 1" while installing scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I have Python 2.7.9 on windows 7 64-bits. I'm trying to install scipy using pip. I used `pip install scipy` but I get the following error :

```
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\us
ers\\admin\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-xpl5cw\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compil
e(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file
__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip-b68pfc-reco
rd\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with
 error code 1 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-xpl5cw\scipy
```

I searched on google and stackoverflow for solutions but nothing worked. I tried upgrading pip and it didn't work too.

Here are my installed packages and their versions :

```
httplib2 (0.9.1)
nltk (3.0.3)
nose (1.3.7)
numpy (1.9.2)
pip (7.0.3)
pytz (2015.4)
scikit-learn (0.16.1)
setuptools (17.1.1)
six (1.9.0)
twilio (4.4.0)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace? You likely need to `sudo apt-get install` a few things along with `scipy` as it has quite a few dependencies. I recall having to do that for a few libraries when installing scipy a while back.

Comment: Get a binary.
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Possible duplicate of here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142839/pip-install-numpy-python-2-7-fails-with-errorcode-1

Comment: @IanAuld, this is Windows. Not Ubuntu or another Linux distro with an aptitude repository.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Agreed, it's a dup. I'm sure I've asked the same question before myself, in fact. I was using a newer version of Python, but the solution is the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Install scipy in Windows 7 with Python 3.4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952349/how-to-install-scipy-in-windows-7-with-python-3-4-2)

Comment: Try to download scipy package from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy)

Comment: You can install scipy as explained in [Scipy website installation instructions](https://www.scipy.org/install.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you'll need to use the unofficial precompiled binaries:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Select the version matching your architecture and Python version.

Comment: @RodolpheLAMPE what do I do once I have downloaded scipy .whl file ? I am using windows 10

Comment: @RodolpheLAMPE Yes, you have to download the version that matches your Python version

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia Just install it `pip install some-package.whl`

Comment: @Hack-R I downloaded the scipy `.whl` file and then when I did `pip install filename.whl` I get : `C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'scipy-0.19.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl'`

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia I'm not able to reproduce the error. Make sure you are using the correct version and architecture. For instance that's only the right file if you have 32-bit Windows and Python 2.7. Almost no one uses 32-bit Windows anymore, so I doubt you downloaded the correct file. Also make sure all dependencies have been met. If you still have the problem please start a new question about it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried installing through pip which kept on failing with error code 1 or took forever to finish (never finished actually!). 
However, the following command worked without a hitch:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

Reference: http://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: **user25111** asked for help for Python + Scipy on Windows. Your answer is for linux systems.

Comment: That's the reason why I had clearly stated this is for Ubuntu. A lot of users, including myself, arrive at this question when looking for a solution for the same problem on a non-windows OS. I added this answer to help the general audience not only the asker.

Answer (score 2):

Installing *setuptools* made it work for me (Mac OS)

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

Comment: This is what fixed the error for me on WSL2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same error when installing **scipy**.

Then I downloaded and installed [MiniConda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). And then I used the below command to install pytables.

```
conda install -c conda-forge scipy
```

Please refer the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem when installing keras on windows10~

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can check below command:

```
python -m pip install psycopg2
```