# Pip installation of scipy.optimize (or scipy correctly(?))

Tags: python, numpy, pip, installation

After uninstalling Anaconda to stop problems with Jupyter notebook kernels, I am trying to run a file which requires

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib import animation
from IPython.display import HTML
from autograd import elementwise_grad, value_and_grad
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import zip_longest
from functools import partial
```

and getting this message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-29781769facb> in <module>()
     10 
     11 from autograd import elementwise_grad, value_and_grad
---> 12 from scipy.optimize import minimize
     13 from collections import defaultdict
     14 from itertools import zip_longest

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>()
     59 __all__ = ['test']
     60 
---> 61 from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
     62 
     63 from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config

ImportError: cannot import name NUMPY_MKL
```

I tried installing `scipy.optimize`:

```
C:\Users\Toni>pip install scipy.optimize
Collecting scipy.optimize
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy.optimize (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for scipy.optimize
```

I'm using Windows 10 on a 64-bit computer, and python 2.7.13.

I did try the following:

```
>C:\Users\Toni>pip install scipy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\python2/\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in c:\python2/\lib\site-package (from scipy)
```

---

PROGRESS NOTES:

OK... It seems as though scipy may have been incorrectly installed (following the lead from the first answer)... So I uninstall it, and then try...

`pip install scipy`

```
failed with error code 1 in c:\users\toni\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-vnjyae\scipy
```

which sends me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919488/4089351), and later on [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), but not so fast, first stop [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) with the conundrum of which one to choose:

```
NumPy, a fundamental package needed for scientific computing with Python.
Numpy+MKL is linked to the Intel® Math Kernel Library and includes required DLLs in the numpy.core directory.
numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl
numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl
numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl
numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl
numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
numpy‑1.13.0+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28568118/4089351) is the key (probably):

Typing `python` on the cmd prompt I get:

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win 32
```

So from `Python 2.7`, I need the `27` version, and from `win 32` I have to disregard the fact that I have a 64-bit computer. So clear...

Comment: try just `pip install scipy`

Comment: @kamik423 Thank you. I tried (edited OP), and curiously it seems as though it is already installed!!! So I have even less of a clue as to why this doesn't work...

Comment: This helped me installing scipy/numpy on windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2114531/3554071

Comment: @engineercoding I thought I had accomplished this by running: `C:\Users\Toni>pip install numpy-1.11.3+mkl-cp2/-cp2/m-win32.whl` returning `Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.11.3+mkl from file:///C:/Users/Toni/numpy-1.11.3%2Bmkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl in c:python27\lib\site-packages`. Am I not using the right wheel?

Answer (score 0):

I've met some similar questions before, remind me that the module had alreadt been installed, but inside the folder it's almost empty. My solution is to

```
pip uninstall MODULENAME
```

Then try another way like reinstall or use wheel

```
pip install MODULENAME.whl
```

Hope that could help you.

Comment: I may uninstall scipy in your case. The latest time I met this problem is about openCV, it told me opencv-python had been installed but it's not. So I uninstalled opencv-python, downloaded a offline wheel file and use it to install, restarted and it worked.

Comment: OK. The package (module (?)) that is causing problems is more specific, though... I think it is `scipy.optimize`...

Comment: Ummm... I'm not sure, in the openCV case I found that I do can `import cv2` but there's no sub-modules, so I uninstalled the entire `opencv-python`.

Comment: it is a sub-folder of scipy. Thus I believe it is.

Comment: After uninstalling `scipy`, and trying to reinstall it, I get a code 1 error, which seems to mean that I need to first [install a bunch of stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919488/4089351). The question is, for my Windows 10 64-bit computer, should I choose the `win32.whl` or `win_amd64.whl`. One would assume the latter, but it doesn't let me do it. So is it the former?

Comment: I don't understand what is " it doesn't let me do it". I'm using 64-bit win10 either, and yet all `win_amd64` wheel file works well... If that doesn't suits you, I think [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) may help you, thought it may be a little large...

Comment: I posted the issue with the links, illustrating how it's not about the computer (32 vs. 64-bit), but the version on Python.

Comment: ... the version you need should be `scipy‑0.19.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy). But again, since many of these packages for science calculation are connected, I still recommend some full Python distribution like [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), [Pythonxy](https://python-xy.github.io/) or [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/). It'll be much easier with them.