# Installing SciPy for Python 3.7 on Mac Os High Sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, intellij-idea, scipy

please help installing SciPy. I think i've tried almost any advice i could find, but still no luck.

I am using Mac High OS Sierra 10.13.1, python 3.7, trying to make this work for IntellIJ IDEA 2017.2 IDE. I have Xcode version 9.2 if that helps.

1. I've tried instaling from IDE, using package installer -> fails with error status code 1.
2. I've tried installing using `pip3 install scipy`
3. I've installed `brew install gcc` ( I have version 7.2.0 installed)
4. I've installed numpy.
5. I've tried to install using Macports as suggested on [official site](https://www.scipy.org/install.html) - didn't help.
6. I've tried to instal using `brew install scipy`.
7. I've tried to install using Conda. It installed somewhere to Conda Dir, but i still cannot access library from python file using import scipy, error: No module named scipy.

Looks like i am just going in loops now, can some one suggest any idea please?

Topics i researched:

- [SciPy build/install Mac Osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821297/scipy-build-install-mac-osx/47827577?noredirect=1#comment82618372_47827577)
- [Can't install Scipy through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575587/cant-install-scipy-through-pip)
- ["failed with error code 1" while installing scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919393/failed-with-error-code-1-while-installing-scipy)
- Some other ones i lost links to.

Comment: What's the errors you are getting? For example using `pip3` approach?

Comment: **Pre-last error:**
Command "gcc-4.2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I
...
...
/folders/7n/l_kpmtds4514nmt3dg2hc5kh0000gn/T/pip-build-_hmtjwc_/scipy/scipy/_build_utils/src/wrap_g77_abi_c.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.7/private/var/folders/7n/l_kpmtds4514nmt3dg2hc5kh0000gn/T/pip-build-_hmtjwc_/scipy/scipy/_build_utils/src/wrap_g77_abi_c.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.7/private/var/folders/7n/l_kpmtds4514nmt3dg2hc5kh0000gn/T/pip-build-_hmtjwc_/scipy/scipy/_build_utils/src/wrap_g77_abi_c.o.d" failed with exit status 12

Comment: **Last error**:
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/7n/l_kpmtds4514nmt3dg2hc5kh0000gn/T/pip-build-_hmtjwc_/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/7n/l_kpmtds4514nmt3dg2hc5kh0000gn/T/pip-myvj70ih-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in ...

Comment: Some additional info, it looks like conda actually installed SciPy, but i cant understand how to access from my IDE.
Commands like 'conda remove scipy' 'conda install scipy' or 'brew remove scipy' 'brew install scipy' work just fine. But i still cant figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like i made it work.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814361/miniconda-installs-numpy-but-python-cant-import-it): helped me.

It appeared I was actaully able to install scipy package using conda. But my Python didn't see the package. So i had to:

1. Change Right Click on my project in IDE > Project > New > Python SDK > Add Local
2. Select Python in Conda dir. In my case it was  `/Users/[my user ]/miniconda3/bin/python3.6`
3. Restart IDE just in case and my python script was able to see `import scipy`.
4. The downside of this - that I cannot install packages the clean way from IDE anymore for some reason. I.e. Tools > Manage Python Packages > + > doesn't find any. And I have to reinstall all the packages i had using `conda install [package name]` from terminal . But I am fine with it, as long as it works.

Hopefully my quest might be useful for someone.